# Meteor Session defined and then all the sudden undefined

Tags: meteor, iron-router

After upgrading to Meteor 1.0.1 (security update) I'm getting some weird behavior (it is possible that's this is due to a package update). First it's defined but then when I navigate to a different page it's undefined.

I have the following in client folder on startup

```
var getUserLanguage;
getUserLanguage = function () {
    var lang;
    lang = void 0;
    if (navigator && navigator.userAgent && (lang = navigator.userAgent.match(/android.*\W(\w\w)-(\w\w)\W/i))) {
        lang = lang[1];
    }
    if (!lang && navigator) {
        if (navigator.language) {
            lang = navigator.language;
        } else if (navigator.browserLanguage) {
            lang = navigator.browserLanguage;
        } else if (navigator.systemLanguage) {
            lang = navigator.systemLanguage;
        } else {
            if (navigator.userLanguage) {
                lang = navigator.userLanguage;
            }
        }
        lang = lang.substr(0, 2);
    }
    console.log("current language is", lang);
    Session.set("currentUserLang", lang);
    console.log('aaa ' + Session.get("currentUserLang"));
    return lang;
};

Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.set("showLoadingIndicator", true);
    TAPi18n.setLanguage(getUserLanguage())
        .done(function () {
            Session.set("showLoadingIndicator", false);
        })
        .fail(function (error_message) {
            // Handle the situation
            //console.log(error_message);
        });
});
```

Then I have the following in my edit template JS file

```
Template.editProducer.rendered = function () {
    // Setup parsley form validation
    $('#form').parsley({trigger: 'change'});

    // sets parsley lang
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
        console.log("lang " + Session.get("currentUserLang"));
        var curentLang =  Session.get("currentUserLang");

        console.log("curentLang " + curentLang);
        if (Session.equals("currentUserLang", curentLang))
            window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale(curentLang);
    });

};
```

I'm getting the following error

edit_producer.js?639fc31a07a550f410d552dfe6242ac967371e3c:15 curentLang undefined
debug.js:41 Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: Error: undefined is not available in the catalog
    at Object.f.setLocale

Comment: I don't think it's the session that's `undefined`, I think the exception comes from `window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale(curentLang)`. However, that I have no experience of.

Comment: The curentLang var is undefined as it's not getting the from the session get which is returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

The issues is with get session returning undefined, I think this due to the fact that meteor renders the template before the session is ready.

To fix this I just added

```
if(curentLang != undefined)
window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale(curentLang);
```